# Multiple select insert data using pivot table Laravel error preg_replace():

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot-table

im folowing Jeffry way tutorial i have done everything from this tutorial [LInK](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/22)
When i insert data from my store function im getting error like below:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 747:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
in helpers.php line 747
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\elixir\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php', '747', array('search' => '\?', 'replace' => array('1', '', '1', '1', '', '1', '', array('1', '2'), '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '1', '2016-08-18 18:15:46', '2016-08-18 18:15:46'), 'subject' => 'insert into `psl_calls` (`branch_id`, `vessel_name`, `port_id`, `jetty_id`, `voyage_no`, `principal_id`, `reference_no`, `purposes`, `eta_estimate_time`, `etb_estimate_time`, `etc_estimate_time`, `etd_estimate_time`, `previous_port_id`, `next_port_id`, `employee_id`, `quality_rating`, `cancel_remark`, `no_cost_time_remark`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, , 1, 1, , 1, , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 'value' => array('1', '2')))
```

My controller function like this :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['user_id'] = \Auth::id();
        $call = PslCall::create($input);
        $call->purposes()->attach($request->input('purposes'));
       // return Redirect::to('/calls');
    }
```

My PslCall model :

```
public function purposes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PslPurpose')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

i have a pivot table call :

```
Schema::create('psl_call_psl_purpose', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('psl_call_id')->unsigned()->index();;
            $table->foreign('psl_call_id')->references('id')->on('psl_calls')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('psl_purpose_id')->unsigned()->index();;
            $table->foreign('psl_purpose_id')->references('id')->on('psl_purposes')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Try `$request->get('purposes')` insead.

Comment: Question about `preg_replace`, but nothing about `preg_replace` given?

Comment: in laravel we can pass array to pivot table ike this ` $call->purposes()->attach($request->input('purposes'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$call->purposes()->attach(['field_name'=> $request->input('purposes')]);
       // return Redirect::to('/calls');
```

Replace `field_name` with your column name of purposes table

Comment: hi im saving this array into pivot table can you check my quz

Comment: try this call->purposes()->attach([$request->input('purposes')]);

Comment: @monash same error bro from the  video everything works buut when i try to inserting step im getting error